# Adding two time values stored as strings in database

Tags: c++, mysql, string, datetime

My SQL table has 6 rows with different time values stored as **varchar(10)** in the format HH:MM:SS and I want to add all these different time values and display the total time

```
TIME VALUES 
------------
12:30:00  
12:30:00  
12:30:00  
12:30:00  
12:30:00  
12:30:00
```

The output should be the sum of all the rows of the column **TIME VALUES** which is ***75*** in this case.

I want to display the total as 75, I am using mysql as my database and using c++ to pass queries to it coupled with mysql.h as a library.
I have tried using `get_time()` and `strptime()` but I havent been successfull.

I cannot use another library to access mysql and I am looking for a C++ code or MYSQL Query that will help me solve this problem.

Comment: *"My SQL table has 6 rows with different time values stored as varchar(10) in the format HH:MM:SS and I want to add all these different time values and display the total time"* The values in your example are all the same..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
SELECT SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(your_column_name))) ...
```

- [`TIME_TO_SEC`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_time-to-sec) will first convert the HH:MM:SS string to seconds.
- [`SUM`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_sum) will add the seconds.
- [`SEC_TO_TIME`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_sec-to-time) will convert back the seconds to HH:MM:SS format.

Comment: it works but displays the final answer as -  **75:00:00.000000**, what should i do if i want the precision only till seconds and ignore the zeroes after the decimal ?

Comment: @KaranMotiramani it is a very basic thing, and you can handle this in your application code (hint: string manipulation)

Comment: i was looking for some sql query to do that, i already handled it using string handling

Comment: @KaranMotiramani check [`Time_format()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_time-format)